# PNG Image Texture Is Not Transparent Using Bump and Noise

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders

I've set up Nodes with Noise and Bump on my main cube shape, and within the same cube shape (new material) I added the same nodes but this time with I added an Image texture so the material can look the same.
I saw a tutorial with a MIX shader and diffuse BSDF, but I'm confused how to set it up, or if it's the right shader to use.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bump map is set up correctly. If you want to use a subsurface color, you need to give the subsurface a vale that is higher than 0 (although low values generally work best). If your .png image has built in alpha channel, you can do it all in one material. You can connect it like this:

[image: ShaderCombo]

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for taking the time to do a Node Set up. I have done the same node set up like yours, but I'm still getting the black background appearing.

https://ibb.co/wQtKhpN

Ill also upload if the file if it's possible so you may see if I made a mistake.

Comment: I also tried increasing and decreasing the subsurface value, but the black background didnt disappear.

Comment: In your nodes, you connected the image color to the mix factor and the image alpha to the mix color. Switch them. Remember - yellow > yellow, grey > grey (for the mostpart).

Comment: Actually I made a small mistake on the Nodes with 2 noodles. But that still didn't change the background.

https://ibb.co/cLgvFsr

Comment: I think you beat me to the comment. If you see my screenshot, I swapped them around.

Comment: The alpha clip was the first thing that come to mind. Also seeing it on a YT tutorial, but that didnt work. Also switched the positions of the color inputs. and the logo had the outline shape of the image. I removed the subsurface and it didnt help.

Comment: https://ibb.co/sCDJry3

Comment: I tried the new node set up, and there's something weird going on, because its not working. Here's another Screen shot. Also you forgot the Bump Node.

https://ibb.co/HtcGvqx

Comment: Sure, please tell me how to upload my file.

Comment: Go to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. Paste in the URL of this question, drag and drop your file in the box. Agree to the terms and click upload. It will give you a link. Edit your question and paste the link there.

Comment: Here's the link:

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Dp80anrk" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Dp80anrk/)

Comment: The setup is fine, you just have a different material assigned to the rest of the box. Drag and select the whole node graph (the one with the image) and copy it(ctrl+c). Select the other (outer box) material, select and delete the node graph. Paste (ctrl+v) the graph you previously copied into the empty space, and connect the principled bsdf to the material output. You can delete all the rest related to the image. It works fine with both bump and subsurface connected. Just make sure the graphs match (except for the image)

Comment: OK, thanks heaps for that Christopher, really appreciate your time for helping me out!

Kind regards.